# Why does the "drop user" command for SQL not work in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Why does the `drop user a_2` command not work when I try to use it in C#, while when I tried it in SQL Server Management Studio, it works there !!???

This is the code that I used it when I create the user & give it a permission:

```
use DataBaseName;
create login a_2 with password='Aa123';
create user a_2 for login a_2;
grant insert to a_2;

..........
```

The connection string used :

```
Data Source=TheServerName;Integrated Security=True;database=master
```

Note:

I tried to drop a database from C# and it works perfectly without any problem, but when I use it to drop a user the problem raised here !!!

This is the exception that gets raised

> Exception is: Cannot drop the user
>   'a_2', because it does not exist or
>   you do not have permission.

Comment: Now its working, after I have changed from "drop user" to "drop login" :)..... Thanks alot Guys;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that "**you do not have permission**". Your application is running as a different user from you. You can solve this by either giving the default application user the necessary permissions on the database (not a good idea) or by creating a special user in the database for your application and having the application run as that user.

Be aware that giving your application (or any user, for that matter) permissions to drop users could be very risky if someone figures out how to hack your application. And you aren't actually including the ability to drop the database in your app, are you? Think about it. Instead of creating users in the database, **consider creating a Users table just for your application**. Then your users won't have such extensive rights to your actual database.

Comment: I'm running the VS in administrator mode & when I test & create the DB and the user I created using the same user account... So, I don't think the impersonate thing is the problem here... since, i'm running the VS in admin also !! It's wared !!!

Comment: Sql Server has the concept of **Logins** and **Users**. Logins are accounts/bindings used to access the physical server itself. You can use Windows/Domain accounts as Logins, or you can use dedicated Sql Server Logins. In you C# app, you're using integrated security, which means you are logging into Sql Server with the same user account that you are running VS as. I would check that the Sql User that your Sql Login (Windows account) is bound to, has the permissions required to drop the user for the respective database.

Comment: I have the permission for drop a user & a database in the sql management... and i test it there... but as i said, in the c# code, is not working... I can't drop the user there...

Answer (score 1):

`DROP USER` would require `use DataBaseName`;

Or a different connection string

```
Data Source=TheServerName;Integrated Security=True;database=DataBaseName
```

That is, the `DROP USER` only makes sense in the context of your database. When you run it later you are in the context of master = fail.

Comment: What about `select DB_NAME`? Same error? Same credentials to the database?

Comment: Why should I use select DB_NAME ?? What is needed for ?? i need to drop a user... I don't get you... could u explain it more for me if u please...

Comment: Sorry, ExecuteScalar see what database you are in. The point is that CREATE USER and DROP USER have the same rights: so something is wrong with your connection or context or credentials.

Comment: Now its working, after I have changed from "drop user" to "drop login" :)..... Thanks alot Guys;)

Comment: In which case you *still* have a user in the database, and you are in the master database... and you did not **follow my suggestions** above...